# Form validation: remove error after onkeydown in input

Tags: javascript

I am working on my first for validation, really basic.

If you leave the 'username' input blank it will turn the username input border red and also place an alert icon in the input.

I am trying to 'remove' what was added when the validation failed as soon as the user starts typing in the input that caused the error.

So the scenario is: The user leaves *Username* blank, clicks *Submit* and then the border of the *Username* input goes red and an error icon appears. They then go back and they add their username into the *Username* input after the first character they type into the *Username* box I want the red border and error icon to disappear.

However my attempts have failed

[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12apmo5j/9/)

JS

```
function contactForm() {
  var theForm = document.forms.contact;
  var errorUsername = document.getElementById('username-error');
  var usernameInput = document.getElementById('username');

  theForm.onsubmit = function() {
    if (theForm.username.value === '') {
      errorUsername.style.display = 'block';
      usernameInput.className = 'form__input form__input--red rounded-4';
      return false;
    } else {
      theForm.username.onkeydown = function() {
        errorUsername.style.display = 'none';
        usernameInput.className = 'form__input rounded-4';
      };
      return true;
    };
  };

};
contactForm();
```

HTML

```
<form name="contact" action="#" novalidate>
  <div class="input__holder">
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="form__input rounded-4" placeholder="Username">
    <div id="username-error" class="input__error">!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="input__holder">
    <input name="password" type="password" class="form__input rounded-4" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="input__holder">
    <input name="email" type="text" class="form__input rounded-4" placeholder="E-mail">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="" class="submit-button rounded-4">Submit</button>
</form>
```

CSS

Too long, in Fiddle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add something like this on javascript

```
document.onkeyup = function() {
    var errorUsername = document.getElementById('username-error');
    var usernameInput = document.getElementById('username');
    if (usernameInput.value.length === 0) return;
    errorUsername.style.display = 'none';
    usernameInput.className = 'form__input rounded-4';
}
```

Here the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/12apmo5j/12/

I think this solves your problem :)

Comment: It does, thank you interesting to see how close yet... far I was!

Comment: If you prefer, you can use the same function to validate the two types of validations, something like this https://jsfiddle.net/12apmo5j/14/

Comment: wow that is a lot nicer thank you, with this if you type and then remove text it alerts the user before even clicking submit. great functionality!